# Discord Bot - Reaction Collector/Embed Edit

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am in the process of creating a Would You Rather command for my bot.
I have everything in place, except one feature I can't work out how to implement.

I would love to have it so that when someone reacts with their answer (️ or ️) the bot then edits the embed and puts the user who replied under their answer like this:

[image]

The code I currently have is:

```
case "wyr":
            embed.setColor('#fc2803')
            embed.setTitle('Would You Rather?')
            embed.setDescription(':a: **Be able to fly** \n \n :b: **Breathe underwater**')
            
            message.channel.send(embed).then(m => m.react('️')).then(r => r.message.react('️'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily implement this using the [discord.js-collector package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-collector).
But if you want to make it using plaine discord.js, then you will have to listen to reactions when sending the embed, and then edit it to what you want like in the example i will give.

#### Simple Example Using The [discord.js-collector package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-collector):

[Code Here](https://github.com/IDjinn/Discord.js-Collector/blob/master/examples/reaction-collector/menu.js)
And [Live Preview Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-collector#reaction-menu)

#### Simple Example Using Plaine Discord.js:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Hello There!");

const embedtosend = await message.channel.send(embed).then(m => m.react('️')).then(r => r.message.react('️'));

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['️', '️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
};


message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 2, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
    const reaction = collected.first();

if (reaction.emoji.name === '️') {
const someotherembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("This Is A Different Hello There!");

    embedtosend.edit(someotherembed)

  } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '️') {
const anotherembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("This Is A Different Embed!");

    embedtosend.edit(anotherrembed)
    
  }
});
```

I haven't tested this code, so it might not work...